Speed up external API call
I need to transform a large set of data, that I get calling an external API. This data contains a lot of urls, and I need to parse them in a certain way and return them.
But the problem is that the request is taking about 10 to 11 seconds, and I need to find a way of speeding up the call. I'm using caching and its working but on later requests, but the first request is always long.
Could you give me some suggestions on some ideas I could do.

Try to provide more information. For example tell us if you have the control over external API (e.g. it is under control of different team in the company). Also provide some code, show us what you are trying to do. From my understanding external API is just slow so you cannot do much with the code that you have no control of
